# CombineLatest inner BackpressureStrategy

Tags: rx-java2

I have two sources of data (Realm). I want to use it combineLatest operator.

Pseudocode:

```
Flowable.combineLatest(
  dataSource1
 .observeOn(Schedulers.io(), false, 1),
  dataSource2
 .observeOn(Schedulers.io(), false, 1),
 1
    )
.observeOn(Schedulers.computation(), false, 1)
// processing
.doOnNext(item -> Thread.sleep(1000)
.subscribe();
```

I use restriction for number of items cached in observeOn operators (I dont need to emit old db cached data).

Is possible emit last item from queue of combineLatest operator? In actual state are emitted all items.

Data emited from db have relativelly big size. For one pair is it ok, but for more not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `onBackpressureLatest`:

```java
Flowable.combineLatest(
    dataSource1
      .onBackpressureLatest()
      .observeOn(Schedulers.io(), false, 1),
    dataSource2
      .onBackpressureLatest()
      .observeOn(Schedulers.io(), false, 1),
    1     
)
.observeOn(Schedulers.computation(), false, 1)
.doOnNext(item -> Thread.sleep(1000)
.subscribe();
```

Comment: I think that it does not solve my problem. In case when processing of data on IO threads is faster than on computation thread. Items will be still added to queue.

Comment: Have you actually tried it? `onBackpressureLatest` will keep at most 1 item, the latest one from source, until that is consumed by its downstream.

Comment: Will queue have max. one item always?

Comment: `onBackpressureLatest` doesn't use a queue itself, but only a slot for the latest item. You already constrain the queue of `observeOn` to hold at most 1 item.

Comment: Sorry, I think queue of combineLatest.

Comment: But maybe can solve this problem usage onBackressureLatest after combineLatest and before last observeOn. Items will be emitted from combineLatest queue imediatelly and will be persisted only last value.